# Woo commerce - Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating an extension plugin for WooCommerce and am getting the error Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null

The code that is causing this is:

```
foreach ( $this->cart_session_data as $key => $default ) {
                $this->$key = WC()->session->get( $key, $default );
            }
```

The full code can be seen here http://pastebin.com/v9e2QrLv

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It seems that WC()->session is NULL. Where is it being defined? Can you debug that variable?

Comment: So... your session is `null`. Where does the `session` get set?